# SVN Error: "' 'x' isn't in the same repository as 'y' " during merge

Tags: svn

I get the error

```
svn: 'x' isn't in the same repository as 'y' "
```

during merge. What's the problem and how can I fix it ?

(I actually know the answer and posting it as soon as I am allowed by the system, so that it's googleable by others. I got my share of trouble finding the answer).

Comment: No idea what this is, but do you have externals in your repo?

Comment: Is this a problem with SVN in general, or is it specific to TortoiseSVN? I encountered this problem using TortoiseSVN. The links in your answer suggest that you use Tortoise SVN as well.

Comment: Thanks for asking the question even though you already knew it. It made my search much easier.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

The problem lies in the fact the checkout information is different from what you specify in the `svn merge` command. Typically, it can be either:

- the hostname is different when you did the checkout. You did the checkout as from `svn.example.com` but now you are merging by referring to an host alias, like `svn-alias.example.com`. note that even the case is important. You can get this error if you do `svn merge` from `SVN.EXAMPLE.COM`. More on this [here](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=4061&viewType=browseAll&dsMessageId=2353722) and [here](http://subversion.tigris.org/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=1065&dsMessageId=2353754).
- the protocol is different from what you used for the checkout. E.g. http://svn.example.com versus https://svn.example.com Make sure you use the same protocol.
- you are specifying a username at `svn merge` in the form `user@svn.example.com`. Try to remove the `user@` specification (the user is passed anyway). svn considers the hostname, and thus the repo, different if you specify the user, even if the user is technically the same.

Comment: Thank you for this post. My only problem was a change in case for my path. If not for your post I'm sure it would have taken me hours to figure out. I also wanted to add that 'must be from the same repository' is another error message for the same issue.

Comment: +1 for mentioning that case is important. I had the exact same problem, and this helped me solve it quickly.

Comment: also +1 for mentioning the user in the uri as well - that just helped me solve my problem as well

Comment: In Tortoise, I was able to complete the merge by editing the url in the "From URL" field to match the casing.

Comment: To change the repository location, use `switch --relocate svn+ssh://currenturl http://newurl ./` or, since version 1.7, `svn relocate http://newurl`

Comment: I had this issue and the protocol point solved it. HTTP vs HTTPS, how silly... Thank you @Stefano Borini!

Answer (score 7):

this is very much case sensitive. Sometimes if you right click in any branch and click merge
https://mysite.com/svn/MYREPO/trunk as merge from . But my branch name has small letters for myrepo
https://mysite.com/svn/myrepo/branches/mybranch.
this cause me error
surely check the case sensitivenes.. If its not matching type in the wizard correctly

Answer (score 1):

The merge is case sensitive.  Ensure when you do the initial checkout ensure that the name and case are the same.  For example, if you checkout to "http:///ABC" ensure you enter "http:///ABC", not "http:///abc" in the "URL to merge from".

Answer (score 0):

You can also get this error if both repositories, despite being separate, have the same UUID. Easily resolved by using the 'svnadmin setuuid' command on one of them.

Answer (score -2):

I just have the same problem and I just cleared the port input and it works